# React Bootstrap CheckBox not toggling 'checked' Prop on Selection

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am fairly new to React Bootstrap and I have been having an annoying issue with checkboxes in a form I am creating.

They won't stay checked when selected after my state updates. They will if I check them again.

I created a toggling function that appends input from selected check boxes in state and sets the checked prop to true. `checked={true}`

I have written it two ways, both not working.

```
handleToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectedBox = "cb" + e.target.value
    this.setState({ goals: this.state.goals + e.target.value, [selectedBox]: e.target.checked })
  }

handleToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectedBox = "cb" + e.target.value
    this.setState({ goals: this.state.goals + e.target.value, [selectedBox]: true })
  }
```

What has been frusturating is that proper values are updating in the state. I threw a debugger in and can see the current state containing a true value for the selected check boxes and the user input appending to whatever is currently under the goals key.

Any direction appreciated. This has been taking a while to debug. Thanks.

Full component -

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, form, FormGroup, Checkbox, Radio, option, ControlLabel, FormControl, ProgressBar, Pagination, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DatePicker from "react-bootstrap-date-picker";
import { handleChange } from '../helpers';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    var value = new Date().toISOString();
    this.state = {
        date: value,
        experience: 1,
        progress: 0,
        active: false,
        goals: "",
        cb1: false,
        cb2: false,
        cb3: false,
        cb4: false,
        cb5: false
    }
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this)
  }

  handleSelect(eventKey) {
    if (this.state.active === false) {
      this.setState({ experience: eventKey, progress: this.state.progress += 20, active: true })
    } else {
      this.setState({ experience: eventKey })
    }
  }

  handleToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectedBox = "cb" + e.target.value
    this.setState({ goals: this.state.goals + e.target.value, [selectedBox]: e.target.checked })
  }

  render() {
    const stats = this.props.user.stats
    if (!stats || stats.length === 0) {
      return(
        <div className="portfolio-form-main">
          <div className="portfolio-form-container-title-div">
            <h1 className="portfolio-title">Profile Information</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="portfolio-form-container">
            <form className="portfolio-form">
              <ProgressBar active now={this.state.progress} />
              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel>Choose Your Goals.</ControlLabel>
                <Checkbox checked={this.state.cb1} onChange={this.handleToggle} value="1" >
                  Lose Some Weight
                </Checkbox>
                {' '}
                <Checkbox checked={this.state.cb2} onChange={this.handleToggle} value="2">
                  Build Strength and Muscle
                </Checkbox>
                {' '}
                <Checkbox checked={this.state.cb3} onChange={this.handleToggle} value="3">
                  General Health and Wellness
                </Checkbox>
                {' '}
                <Checkbox checked={this.state.cb4} onChange={this.handleToggle} value="4">
                  Compete in an Event
                </Checkbox>
                {' '}
                <Checkbox checked={this.state.cb5} onChange={this.handleToggle} value="5">
                  Rehab an Injury
                </Checkbox>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel>Rate Your Exercise Experience Level.</ControlLabel>
                <Pagination
                  bsSize="medium"
                  items={10}
                  activePage={this.state.experience}
                  onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                  />
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel>When is Your Birthday?</ControlLabel>
                  {' '}
                <DatePicker value={this.state.value}/>
              </FormGroup>
              <ControlLabel>How Tall Are You?</ControlLabel>
              {' '}
              <Form inline>
                <FormGroup>
                  <FormControl type="number"/>
                  {' '}
                    <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
                      <option value="select">Unit</option>
                      <option value="other">in</option>
                      <option value="other">cm</option>
                    </FormControl>
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
              <ControlLabel>How Much Do You Weigh?</ControlLabel>
              {' '}
              <Form inline>
                <FormGroup>
                  <FormControl type="number"/>
                  {' '}
                    <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
                      <option value="select">Unit</option>
                      <option value="other">Lbs</option>
                      <option value="other">Kgs</option>
                    </FormControl>
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
              <FormGroup >
                <ControlLabel>Tell Us About Yourself.</ControlLabel>
                  {' '}
                <FormControl componentClass="textarea" placeholder="textarea" />
              </FormGroup>
              <Button bsStyle="primary">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>{stats.birthdate}</li>
          <li>{stats.weight} {stats.weight_unit}</li>
          <li>{stats.height} {stats.height_unit}</li>
          <li>{stats.experience}</li>
          <li>{stats.about_me}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }


}

export default Portfolio
```

Comment: Well I got it to work by causing a page refresh on the handle toggle function.  

```this.props.requestUser(this.props.match.params.userId);``` But it kind of seems wrong....so any input still appreciated on properly handling this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Removing `e.preventDefault()` from the `handleToggle` function in your answer should eliminate the need for a forced page refresh.

When a checkbox is clicked React compares the previous value with the next value to decide whether a change has occurred. If it has then a change event is queued.

It seems that React queries the DOM for the checked value before `handleToggle` is called, so the checkbox value is True. Then `preventDefault()` executes so the checkbox value in the DOM is now False, but React has set the value as True.

So when using `preventDefault()` with checkboxes (and possibly radio buttons) you get inconsistencies between the DOM and React.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't be sorry, just add some more detail around e.preventDefault() and how OP to detect that this is the issue in the future and this will be a great post! After that, in 3 years time when we see your rep in the 100s or 1000s your comment is going to look a little strange ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for selecting and deselecting checkboxes and setting state, adding and removing checked values.

```
handleToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectedBox = "cb" + e.target.value
    if (this.state.goals.includes(e.target.value)) {
      const goal = this.state.goals.replace(e.target.value, '')
      this.setState({ goals: goal, [selectedBox]: e.target.checked })
    } else {
      this.setState({ goals: this.state.goals + e.target.value, [selectedBox]: e.target.checked })
    }
    this.props.requestUser(this.props.match.params.userId);
  }
```